# function to determine if a specific string of characters exists in an array

Tags: arrays, string, excel, vba

Given an array, I would like to have a function which determines if a string of characters exists in an array.
The string of characters must be EXACTLY the same in input of the function, and the array content.

```
Function IsInArray(ThsStrng As String, arr() As String, bnd As Integer) As Boolean
  For Z = 1 To bnd
    If arr(Z) = ThsStrng Then
      IsInArray = True
    Else
      IsInArray = False
    End If
  Next Z
End Function
```

At first, it seemed like the function ran correctly. After using this function a few times, I noticed that the False value (meaning that the input string does not equal to a value in the array), was not correct (there were input values that were exactly the same a value in the array).

Please help,

Comment: why not `IsNumeric(Application.Match("string to look for",arrayVariable,0))`? it will be true if an exact match exists and be false if not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine what happens when the match is found in the middle of the array. The next iteration will be a mismatch, and the return value gets set back to `False`. You need to stop the loop when a match is found.

I believe the VBA syntax for that is

```
Exit For
```

Comment: `Exit Function` would also have done it. But `Exit For` is definitely more appropriate.